# What’s the physical meaning of (∂v/∂T )P?

Tags: thermodynamics, equation-of-state, van-der-waals-behavior

I'm solving this exersice:

The equation of state of a Van der Waals gas is

\begin{equation}
  \left(P + \frac{a}{v^2}\right)(v-b) = RT
  \tag{1}
\end{equation}

Where $a$,$b$ and $R$ are constants.

1. Calculate $(\partial P/\partial v)_T$ and $(\partial P/\partial
       T)_v$
2. Use the results of 1 to calculate $(\partial v/\partial
       T)_P$. What's the physical meaning of this partial derivative?

From equation 1 we have:
\begin{equation}
  P  = \frac{RT}{(v-b)} - \frac{a}{v^2}
\end{equation}

**Solutionf for 1.1.**

\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    \left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial v}\right)_T & = \frac{\partial}{\partial v} \left[\frac{RT}{(v-b)} - \frac{a}{v^2}\right]                                         \\
                                                 & = \frac{\partial}{\partial v} \left[\frac{RT}{(v-b)}\right] - \frac{\partial}{\partial v}\left[\frac{a}{v^2}\right]
                                                 & = \frac{\partial}{\partial v} \left[\frac{RT}{(v-b)}\right] - \frac{\partial}{\partial v}\left[\frac{a}{v^2}\right]
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \boxed{
    \left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial v}\right)_T= \frac{RT}{(v-b)^2} - \frac{2a}{v^3}
  }
  \tag{2}
\end{equation}

**Solution 1.2.**

\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    \left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_v & = \frac{\partial}{\partial T} \left[\frac{RT}{(v-b)} - \frac{a}{v^2}\right]                                         \\
                                                 & = \frac{\partial}{\partial T} \left[\frac{RT}{(v-b)}\right] - \frac{\partial}{\partial T}\left[\frac{a}{v^2}\right]
                                                 & = \frac{\partial}{\partial T} \left[\frac{RT}{(v-b)}\right] - \frac{\partial}{\partial T}\left[\frac{a}{v^2}\right]
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \boxed{
    \left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_v= \frac{R}{(v-b)}
  }
  \tag{3}
\end{equation}

**Solution 2.**

\begin{equation}
  \left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial v}\right)_T
  \left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial T}\right)_P = -
  \left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_v
  \tag{4}
\end{equation}

substituting 2 and 3 in 4
\begin{equation}
  \left(\frac{RT}{(v-b)^2} - \frac{2a}{v^3}\right)
  \left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial T}\right)_P = -
  \frac{R}{(v-b)}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    \left(\frac{RTv^3 - 2a(v-b)^2}{v^3 (v-b)^2}\right)\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial T}\right)_P & = - \frac{R}{(v-b)}                                                   \\
    \left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial T}\right)_P                                                   & = - \frac{R}{(v-b)}\left(\frac{v^3 (v-b)^2}{RTv^3 - 2a(v-b)^2}\right)
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \boxed{
    \left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial T}\right)_P  = - \frac{R v^3 (v-b)}{RTv^3 - 2a(v-b)^2}
  }
\end{equation}

Which I think is all OK. But I don't find any good answer to the question "**What's the physical meaning of $(\partial v/\partial T)_P$?**"

Comment: Isobaric thermal expansion of the real gas. For ideal gas, as v=RT/p, (dv/dT)p = R/p. If you take a=b=0 for ideal gas, you get from your last equation v/T, which is equal R/p.

Comment: It's not that mysterious. The mathematical expression is just shorthand for "the change in volume with change in temperature, when holding pressure constant". For ideal gases it is a property independent of the identity of the gas. For non-ideal gases, it depends on the degree of attraction between the molecules and on the excluded volume.

Comment: as an aside its hard to calculate $dv/dT$ but easy to calculate $dT/dv=1/(dv/dT)$

Comment: Isn't that the same as minus the partial derivative of molar entropy with respect to pressure at constant temperature?